# Cache successfully loaded data, reset state on error, retry next click

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I would like to build the following pattern using an observable:

- On button click, try and fetch a value from the server. If the server responds successfully, keep that value and make no more requests for the lifetime.
- If the request fails, emit an error and reset the state so that a retry can occur on the next button click.

It would look roughly like this:

```js
const loader$ = doFetch().pipe(
  map(response => {
    if (response.isSuccess) {
      return response.value;
    }
    // Emit some error
    // ?? Don't share the result, retry when the button is clicked the next time
  }),
  shareReplay(1)
)
const value$ = btnClick$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => loader$)
);

value$.subscribe(x => {
  console.log(x);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, when a chain emits and `error` notification it's always disposed after that (because one chain can emit only one `error` notification). This means that you'll probably need to cache the result in a BehaviorSubject (or a local variable):

```
const cache$ = new ReplaySubject(1);

const value$ = btnClick$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => merge(
    cache$,
    doFetch(),
  ),
  take(1),
  tap(val => cache$.next(val)),
)

value$.subscribe(...);
```

`merge()` will subscribe to both source Observables at the same time. However,  the first one (`cache$`) is a ReplaySubject that re-emits its buffer immediately on subscription and thanks to `take(1)` it will never trigger the HTTP request of there's already a cached value.

An error notification will be propagated as usual.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was wondering whether I could use the `resetOnError` option from `share`, but I wasn't able to find many good examples.

Comment: I understand what you mean but `resetOnError` is good when the source Observable has long lifespan and sometime it errors. But your use-case is different. You know that when it's successfull you always want to return the same value forever.

Answer (score 0):

1. `clickOnce$` -> take 1 click, and ignores click event
2. concat `clickOnce$` and `doFetch`
3. `retry` when error
4. `shareReplay` value

```
const clickOnce$ = btnClick$.pipe(take(1), ignoreElements());
const value$ = concat(clickOnce$, doFetch()).pipe(retry(), shareReplay(1));

value$.subscribe(...);
```